# Вставить ссылку на php javascript

Tags: javascript

к странице подключается js файл с кодом:

```
window.onload=function(){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "new";
div.innerHTML = "сюда нужно вставить код из другого файла например form.php";
document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

как вставить код из файла form.php он довольно большой чтобы прямо сюда его пихать.
С jquery делал с помощью

```
  $.get("/callme/tpl/form.php", function(data) {
    $(".callme").html(data);
```

но надо без использования jquery
во время генерации страницы

Подскажите?

Comment: вы что хотите вставить текст во время генерации страницы или получить его например динамически по ajax ?

Comment: во время генерации страницы

Comment: а с использованием чистого js ?

Comment: на чистом js да

Comment: тогда смотрите про что-то типа XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что значит "во время генерации страницы", если это процесс формирования html на сервере то это одно. Если это процесс парсинга DOM и рендинга страницы на в браузере то это другое.  А еще что значит "вставить код из файла form.php" то есть должен быть просто исходный текст программы на php в теле страницы или все таки результат выполнения php скрипта?

Comment: во время рендеринга страницы в браузере. это должен быть результат скрипта (в принципе там html код сохраненный как php)